# Skype for Business for Linux Users

Tags: linux, skype

I am looking for good alternative(if it is possible) for Skype for Bussines for Linux users. I know about Pidgin trick, about third party software like TelRed.

My question sounds:

Do any of You dear Users know good solution for Linux user which resolve problem with lack of native support for Skype for Business ?

I know about portal.offcie365 and Web Client but my users wanna use S4B on Linux for video conversation not only for message.

I am looking for free/open source solutions or cheap.

Comment: You may try : [linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) or [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/)

Comment: We have the same issue here. At first I used Sky (TelRed). But it crashes a lot and floods my desktop with stupid error messages. I ended up using Pidgin for Messages and I start my Windows VM with Lync for Calls. If someone tries to call me while my Windows VM is down, I receive an Email and can call back.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: What features do you need? I see video chat between the lines. Conferences? Texting? File exchange? Desktop sharing? …?

Comment: @ zarqos.os [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) and [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/) doesn't support S4B it can be good alternative but  i don't wanna support two different platforms for communication. Unfortunately i don't have idea how i can resolve my problem. Idea with VW sounds good but users didn't want change systems they wanna only Linux and native solutions.